# Error when running git pull origin master

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a newbie in using git version control, I got this error when running git `pull origin master`, this is the error :

```
From /opt/mygit/abc
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Untracked working tree file 'nbproject/private/rake-d.txt' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting
```

Am I miss something? thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that you have the file `nbproject/private/rake-d.txt` in your local repository, but not tracked by git.

Meanwhile, it has been added to the remote repository since your last pull, so doing a pull would overwrite that file, and thus git is warning you that that would happen and aborting the pull.

To resolve this, you'll need to go and either delete or rename the file.

If you want to automate this, run a `git clean` to clean out the folder of untracked files (that is, delete them). It might be a good idea to run `git clean -n` first, though, which merely lists the files it's going to delete, letting you see if there's anything important it plans on deleting.

Alternatively, you could add the file to the repository (remember to commit it), and then pull. git will then try to merge your local copy with the remote one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use first

```
git clean -f -d
```

(or git reset --hard HEAD ) to clean your untracked files then do a

```
git pull
```

Keep in mind this will delete any untracked files

Comment: Thanks nvm, but I still got the same error when running git lull after running get clean error -n.

Comment: @Aditya Hastungkoro Hadi: try git clean -f -d or add an additional -n to see what would be deleted by git clean -f -d before actually do it

Comment: Watch out with this. `git clean -f -d` will permanently delete all files that are not part of the repo - even important ones or ones that are specified in .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if you are getting the pulling error due to untracked worked....

 try it...

go to your project location



 $ cd /usr/local

    $ git fetch origin

    $ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're using NetBeans for development here. I generally add such IDE-specific objects to .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is remove the local untracked copy. What's happening is that a file exists remotely, but not locally. git will not allow you to overwrite a local untracked file.

you have to use `ctrl+shift+F10` its useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are newly started git then follow these steps :

Let's suppose your git repository url is https://github.com/absuser/repo.git

And you want to push your project on this repository with branch name 'testbranch' and your code on your machine at '/home/ubuntu/Documents/code'

Now let's start :

press ctrl+alt+T to open your terminal.

```
$ cd /home/orange/Documents/code

$ git init
```

Create branch on local
    $ git checkout -b testbranch

Add remote repository
    $ git remote add origin https://github.com/absuser/repo.git

Verify added remote
    $ git remote -v

```
$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"

$ git config --global user.name "username"

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "my first comit "

$ git push origin testbranch
```

Now your code pushed on git now .

In case if someone else also committed the code on same branch and you want to merge all the changes with your code on your local machine and push to git then follow these steps :

First you have to stagged your all updated files .

```
$ git add .

$ git pull origin testbranch
```

If any conflict occurs then resolved that and do following steps

```
$ git add .
```

otherwise go ahead

```
$ git commit -m 'merged changes from master'

$ git push origin testbranch
```