# Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

How do I resolve a git merge conflict in favor of pulled changes?

I want to remove all conflicting changes from a working tree without having to go through all of the conflicts with `git mergetool`, while keeping all conflict-free changes. Preferably, I want to do this while pulling, not afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git merge -s ours, what about "theirs"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-theirs)

Comment: Duplicate of [git pull from remote.. can I force it to overwrite rather than report conflicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785107/git-pull-from-remote-can-i-force-it-to-overwrite-rather-than-report-conflicts) You can see the same solution there.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Accepted answer there doesn't answer this questions, so clearly it isn't a duplicate. Plus, that other question is quite ambiguous: it is very hard to tell what is asked. All in all I can't agree with you. What is you point in this?

Comment: @sanmai You have two answers - and you accepted one of them.  Can you better explain what you are expecting in an answer and how much more detail do you want here?

Comment: @EdwardThomson well, actually I was thinking to give this reputation for the first answer, but if you ask, I might wait and see if a better answer comes up

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you're already in conflicted state, and do not want to checkout path one by one. You may try

```
git merge --abort
git pull -X theirs
```

Comment: Straight to the point. Excellent!

Comment: for me I used ```git merge <your-branches> -X theirs```

Comment: `git pull -r origin main -X theirs`

Comment: Instead of `git pull origin <my-branch-name>` I do `git pull origin <my-branch-name> -X theirs` to get everything from upstream and overwrite any tracked files I have with their version. You can also do a `git pull` and then settle the merge conflicts, but when there are many conflicts, the `-X theirs` is what you want.

Comment: This does not allow you to choose merge strategy for individual files. Use `git checkout --theirs <file>` for such requirement.

Answer (score 2214):

```
git pull -s recursive -X theirs <remoterepo or other repo>
```

Or, simply, for the default repository:

```
git pull -X theirs
```

[If you're already in conflicted state...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33569970/93540)

```
git checkout --ours path/to/file
```

> Note that during `git rebase` and `git pull --rebase`, *ours* and *theirs* may appear swapped; `--ours` gives the version from the branch the changes are rebased onto, while `--theirs` gives the version from the branch that holds your work that is being rebased.
> [`git checkout` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/2.27.0)

Comment: Note that `-s recursive` here is redundant, since that's the default merge strategy. So you could simplify it to `git pull -X theirs`, which is basically equivalent to [`git pull --strategy-option theirs`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10697551/456814).

Comment: If I do this, I end up back in the `MERGING` state. I can then `git merge --abort` and try again, but each time I end up with a merge occurring. … I know that a rebase was pushed to my upstream though, so perhaps that's causing this?

Comment: Be careful with `git checkout --theirs path/to/file`. Used it during rebase and got unexpected results. Found explanation in doc:
_Note that during git rebase and git pull --rebase, ours and theirs may appear swapped; --ours gives the version from the branch the changes are rebased onto, while --theirs gives the version from the branch that holds your work that is being rebased._

Comment: Note that `git checkout --theirs/--ours path` man page states that it works for **unmerged paths**. So if there were no conflict in path, it is already merged this command will do nothing. This might case issues when you want for example 'theirs' version of a whole sub-folder. So in such case it would be safer to do `git checkout MERGE_HEAD path` or use commit hash.

Comment: `git pull -X theirs` creates a merge commit if there are conflicts (e.g. if another committer ran `git push -f` to the remote). If you don't want merge commits, run instead `git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: One thing to note with this technique is that, if you're not happy with the result of the `checkout` command, you can run it again with the `--conflict=merge` option to get the full conflict markers in the file again.

Comment: `git checkout --theirs .`

Comment: *NB*: `git checkout --theirs path/glob` doesn't resolve conflicts using ours/theirs. It takes the entire file from either `ours/theirs`. If there are changes that are not conflicts, they will be discarded.

Comment: This approach failed with: "CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename ..." and "CONFLICT (file location):..."

Comment: `git checkout --theirs .` doesn't work as I have files deleted by theirs. I can't `--force` either because these two options are mutually exclusive for unfathomable reasons. The **only** thing that worked for me is vscode, select all Merge Changes files → right click → Accept All Incoming

Comment: ⁺¹ to @CervEd's comment; the answer is also technically incorrect, because the `--theirs/ours` options do not resolve conflicts *(see the comment for details)*. AFAIK git didn't implement such capability, even though I personally find needing "conflict resolution in preference of theirs/ours" far more often than the actual functional of `--theirs/ours` options. I use Emacs' `smerge-keep-upper` and `smerge-keep-lower` instead.

Answer (score 1397):

You can use the recursive "theirs" strategy *option*:

```
git merge --strategy-option theirs
```

From the [man](http://jk.gs/git-merge.html):

```
ours
    This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by 
    favoring our version. Changes from the other tree that do not 
    conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result.

    This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which does 
    not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards 
    everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that
    happened in it.

theirs
    This is opposite of ours.
```

Note: as the man page says, the "ours" merge **strategy-option** is very different from the "ours" merge **strategy**.

Comment: Here is more detailed explanation: http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2010/01/29/how-to-resolve-a-binary-file-conflict-with-git/

Comment: Also `git checkout --theirs` to operate on a single conflicting file

Comment: This doesn't work if you are already in the conflict resolution state. In that case I believe the best way to resolve is to `git checkout <ref to theirs> -- the/conflicted.file`; and then `git add` their changes.

Comment: @ThorSummoner In that case, there is git checkout --theirs path/of/file. That way, you don't have to manually look up the correct hash.

Comment: @Ikke That should basically be its own answer (and the accepted answer at that) if you ask me.

Comment: "git merge local/master --strategy-option theirs" worked for me

Comment: I get `error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.`

Comment: Could you update this answer for `Git 2.0+`? Because from 2.0 onwards `git merge` does no longer have `--strategy-option`. There is only `--strategy`, but this option does not have a `theirs` strategy. Choices are `octopus`, `ours`, `recursive` (default?!), `resolve`, `subtree`.

Comment: @daniel451 Why do you think that option has been removed? It's still available. See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge--Xltoptiongt

Comment: Nevermind, I just noticed that my zsh-setup apparently lacks auto-completion support for `--strategy-option` and I have overlooked this option..

Comment: @dvd that's exactly the option I was looking for. I want to initiate the merge as usual, but when resolving the conflicts, I want to be able to resolve individual files with the appropriate strategy. Thank you!

Comment: I did with git merge OTHER_BRANCH_NAME --strategy-option theirs

Comment: If you're already in the conflict resolution state, you can cancel the merge by first doing `git merge --abort`, and then using `git merge <branch_name> --strategy-option theirs`.

Comment: `git merge --strategy-option theirs BRANCH_THEIRS` still generated conflicts to me ...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Merge it properly where you can and accept theirs (ours) where can't. Saved me tons of time resolving conflicts manually.

Comment: lol, it's classic git to have two very similar-sounding commands that do very different things. it'd be so easy to absent-mindedly confuse "strategy" and "option"!

Comment: Merging a branch that reintroduces a file that was deleted in the target branch with `--ours` still ends in conflict.

Answer (score 791):

If you're already in conflicted state, and you want to just accept *all* of theirs:

```
git checkout --theirs .
git add .
```

If you want to do the opposite:

```
git checkout --ours .
git add .
```

This is pretty drastic, so make sure you really want to wipe everything out like this before doing it.

Comment: or, don't use the `.` and specify the file(s) in place of the dot that you want to checkout. less "drastic" & exactly what you want to do, presumably.

Comment: Have I missed something, or don't you have to `git reset` the conflicted files **before** `git checkout`?

Comment: this doesn't work if the file has been removed from the other branch:  '<file>' does not have their version

Comment: Would upvote more if I could, keep coming back to this answer every now and then.

Comment: Use `git add -u` instead to skip files that are not under version control.

Comment: Hypothetical case, three changes in a file, one conflicting, two without conflict, would this solution apply non conflicting changes and resolve the conflicting change to ours? Or would it take only ours version ignoring non conflicting changes from theirs?

Comment: @Japster @SudiptaBasak So [that `-u` was magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190409/whats-the-difference-between-git-add-and-git-add-u). Thanks!

Comment: If its Monday morning and you haven't yet had coffee. Running the command above doesn't move the files from a "both modified" state.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that like most git actions you can apply this to paths, e.g. `git checkout --theirs wp-content/languages/` which will grab just files under that path from the incoming branch, and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: @pedromarce `git checkout --ours ` takes **all** ours changes including non conflicting. Be careful with that.

Comment: Does `--theirs` mean `Incoming change`? While `--ours` mean `Current change`?

Comment: @tonix, always interpret git terminology from the perspective of a paranoid Linus Torvalds protecting linux from outside changes. If you apply that mindset, then yes "theirs" means the change being merged in (or merge candidate) and "ours" means the side that will receive the merge (the branch that will be updated).

Notice, all of this is strictly based on the orientation of the git merge command (not your larger purpose or a local / origin setup, etc). I hate the "ours/theirs" terminology because it has a technical meaning in the `git merge` which can be opposite of how it sounds.

Comment: `ours` and `theirs` refers to `HEAD` and whatever is being merged into `HEAD`, ie the current commit checked out. Think of `ours` as *current* and `theirs` as *incoming*, not as in what's your work vs. others. What is ours/theirs will depend on if you're resolving a conflict from stash/rebase/merge. *NB* that `git checkout --ours/--theirs` just picks one version and **completely discards** the other. Ie. this answer is probably not what you want. See my answer for how to only discard conflicting changes

Answer (score 248):

OK so, picture the scenario I was just in:

You attempt a `merge`, or maybe a `cherry-pick`, and you're stopped with

```
$ git cherry-pick 1023e24
error: could not apply 1023e24... [Commit Message]
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Now, you view the conflicted file and you really don't want to keep your changes. In my case above, the file was conflicted on just a newline my IDE had auto-added. To undo your changes and accept their's, the easiest way is:

```
git checkout --theirs path/to/the/conflicted_file.php
git add path/to/the/conflicted_file.php
```

The converse of this (to overwrite the incoming version with your version) is

```
git checkout --ours path/to/the/conflicted_file.php
git add path/to/the/conflicted_file.php
```

Surprisingly, I couldn't find this answer very easily on the Net.

Comment: Note that, if one performs a `git status` between `checkout` and `add`, the file still shows as "both modified".

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this for all files that are in a conflicted state? If so it'd be a nice extension to your answer.

Comment: I do this:   `git reset --hard`  and then  `git pull [remote server name] [branch name] -Xtheirs` (undoes the merge then pulls the new stuff on top of my stuff) - not sure if this what you want.

Answer (score 66):

The `git pull -X theirs` answers may create an ugly merge commit, or issue an

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

If you want to simply ignore any local modifications to files from the repo, for example on a client that should always be a mirror of an origin, run this (replace `master` with the branch you want):

```
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```

How does it work? [`git fetch` does `git pull` but without merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?rq=1). Then [`git reset --hard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english) makes your working tree match the last commit. All of your local changes to files in the repo will be [discarded](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---hard), but new local files will be left alone.

Comment: +1 - `git fetch && git reset --hard {remote}/{branch}` was what solved my problem. I needed to completely ditch my own changes in favour of "theirs" state of a branch, but the `git pull -X theirs` choked on some moved/renamed files. Thanks!

Comment: but if I do `git pull` afterwards I go back to conflicting state, may be I shouldn't have git pulled, but why not?

Answer (score 28):

Please not that sometimes this will **not work**:

> git checkout --ours path/to/file

or

> git checkout --theirs path/to/file

I did this instead, assuming **HEAD is ours** and **MERGE_HEAD is theirs**

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file
```

or:

```
git checkout MERGE_HEAD -- path/to/file
```

After we do this and we are good:

```
git add .
```

If you want to understand more, see wonderful post of torek here : 
[git checkout --ours does not remove files from unmerged files list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438168/git-checkout-ours-does-not-remove-files-from-unmerged-files-list)

Answer (score 25):

**VS Code (integrated Git) IDE Users:**

If you want to accept ***all the incoming changes in the conflict file*** then do the following steps.

```
1. Go to command palette - Ctrl + Shift + P
2. Select the option - Merge Conflict: Accept All Incoming
```

Similarly you can do for other options like **Accept All Both, Accept All Current etc.,**

Comment: That seems to only work for a single file, not all files with conflicts though.

Answer (score 24):

To resolve all conflicts with the version in a particular branch:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout ${branchName}
```

So, if you are already in the merging state, and you want to keep the master version of the conflicting files:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs git checkout master
```

Comment: And for people on windows without access to pipe xargs, how does this translate?

Comment: Wouldn't it skip your changes completely? Even those which are not in conflict state?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Unfortunately it subsequently requires either a `git cherry-pick --continue` *or* a `git commit --allow-empty` command to commit these changes, and there seems to be no system behind which command is required, which makes automating this a pain. I’m currently solving this by testing for the existence of a `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file but that seems hacky and brittle, and I’m not yet convinced that it always works.

Comment: This is good, means if you manually resolve some (and do `git add`) then you can bulk resolve the rest via this. `git checkout --ours` / `git checkout --theirs` is useful too.

Answer (score 22):

***Update 2024!***

If you want to accept all current changes and ignore any incoming changes, you could accomplish this:

```
git merge [branch] --strategy-option ours
```

`[branch]` should be replaced with the name of the branch you are merging into your current branch.

If, instead, you know you want to overwrite any current changes and accept all conflicts from incoming changes, you can use the `theirs` strategy instead:

```
git merge [branch] --strategy-option theirs
```

Comment: `[branch]` could be `origin/yourbranchname`

Comment: Could also use `git merge [branch] -X theirs` (`-X` being an alias for `--strategy-option`, more details available via `git merge --help`).

Answer (score 19):

`git checkout --ours/theirs` doesn't exclusively resolve conflicts. It checks out (takes the entire file) from either `ours/theirs`.

Suppose we have a file `foo` with changes in two commits/branches/trees/whatever. If there was a conflict introduced by theirs, as well as a modification, and we want to resolve the conflict using `ours` -- then using `checkout --ours foo` will discard the changes introducing conflicts, but also the modifications.

## Using SED

### Resolve using theirs:

`sed -i -e '/^<<<<<<</,/^=======/d' -e '/^>>>>>>>/d' foo`

- `-i` Modify the file in place,
- `/^<<<<<<</,/^=======/d` delete everything between and including `<<<<<<<` and `=======` (ours)
- `/^>>>>>>>/d` delete the remaining conflict marker
- `-e` specify multiple patterns to SED
- `foo` the file

### Resolve using ours:

`sed -i -e '/^<<<<<<</d' -e '/^=======/,/^>>>>>>>/d' foo`

I made a [script](https://github.com/CervEdin/gut/blob/main/git-resolve.sh) that you can call `git resolve -o/-t/-b`.

### Creating a custom merge tool

You can create custom merge tools. Building on the above `sed` scripts you can put something like this in your `git-config`:

```
[mergetool "ours"]
    cmd = "sed -i -e '/^<<<<<<</d' -e '/^=======/,/^>>>>>>>/d' -- $MERGED"
```

and call it `git mergetool --tool=ours`

### Merge styles

Note that there are other non-standard merge styles, like `diff3` and `zdiff3` as pointed out by @Stavros in the comments. The number of conflict markers is also not hard coded to 7 in git. I believe it's mainly just a default and as I recall, it can be configured.

The basic `sed` script can be [tweaked](https://github.com/CervEdin/gut/commit/4d784fd8c753d8ebc272a190c7ec357738e68e0a) to work with all configurations.

Comment: I started discussion about it on a Git mailing list it for a possible solution:  
https://public-inbox.org/git/3e1548ab-5e20-9555-bd10-d6cbf2ffbce4@gmail.com/

Comment: This problem with the whole file being checked out instead of just resolving the actual merge conflicts is why I found all other answers not helpful and even wrong based on the question wording. It's surprising and unfortunate thought that there is no integrated tool for this in git and sed has to be used instead.

Comment: This answer highlights a criticial and subtle point on what `git merge --theirs|--ours` do, i.e pick the whole file from theirs or ours branch. Currently there is no built-in command line option in git to resolve _ONLY_ the conflict part, picking theirs or ours. This can only be done by manual editing. Some merge tools (e.g Tortoise, P4, kdf3 etc) help. The `sed` option in this answer is handy and the one closest to a command line option.

Comment: @FractalSpace you can use the linked script (I've updated it), put it in your path to run `git resolve -t/--theirs -o/--ours -b/--both -a/--add`. Bug reports and PRs are welcomed and appreciated

Comment: @CervEd I am using your linked script and it is working fine so far (thanks). Also the version I am using does not have `-a`, but it adds the files after resolving conflict (which is good).

Comment: @CervEd as for feedback, an option to be able to pick 'hunks' for either side would be nice. Also, instead of 'both', I prefer something like 'thersthenours' and 'oursthentheirs', matching what most gui tools offer.

Comment: @FractalSpace Awesome! The `-a` flag was added to specifically add. Sometimes I don't want to add but rather do different things with the resolved files. What's the difference of 'theirsthenours' and 'oursthentheirs'? `--both`, treats both as valid, and will "accept" both sides. I've thought about hunks but I personally prefer `vimdiff` in most such cases. The script is mainly designed to be how I would expect `checkout --ours/--theirs` to work and quickly but roughly resolve conflicts in favor to either side. Personally, I use hunks after such a resolution to do anything more granular

Comment: @bam Looks like your git thread is dead

Comment: For `merge.conflictStyle == ?diff3`, `ours` `sed` becomes:

`sed -i -e '/^<<<<<<</d' -e '/^|||||||/,/^>>>>>>>/d' -- $MERGED`

Comment: @Stavros I didn't know about conflict styles, thanks! It shouldn't be hard to match either default, diff3 or zdiff3

Answer (score 5):

> from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging
>
> This will basically do a fake merge. It will record a new merge commit
>   with both branches as parents, but it will not even look at the branch
>   you’re merging in. It will simply record as the result of the merge
>   the exact code in your current branch.
>
> ```
> $ git merge -s ours mundo
> ```
>
> Merge made by the 'ours' strategy.
>
> ```
> $ git diff HEAD HEAD~
> ```
>
> You can see that there is no difference between the branch we were on
>   and the result of the merge.
>
> This can often be useful to basically trick Git into thinking that a
>   branch is already merged when doing a merge later on. For example, say
>   you branched off a release branch and have done some work on it that
>   you will want to merge back into your master branch at some point. In
>   the meantime some bugfix on master needs to be backported into your
>   release branch. You can merge the bugfix branch into the release
>   branch and also merge -s ours the same branch into your master branch
>   (even though the fix is already there) so when you later merge the
>   release branch again, there are no conflicts from the bugfix.

A situation I've found to be useful if I want master to reflect the changes of a new topic branch. I've noticed that -Xtheirs doesn't merge without conflicts in some circumstances...
e.g.

```
$ git merge -Xtheirs topicFoo 

CONFLICT (modify/delete): js/search.js deleted in HEAD and modified in topicFoo. Version topicFoo of js/search.js left in tree.
```

In this case the solution I found was

```
$ git checkout topicFoo
```

from topicFoo, first merge in master using the -s ours strategy, this will create the fake commit that is just the state of topicFoo.
$ git merge -s ours master

check the created merge commit

```
$ git log
```

now checkout the master branch

```
$ git checkout master
```

merge the topic branch back but this time use the -Xtheirs recursive strategy, this will now present you with a master branch with the state of topicFoo.

```
$ git merge -X theirs topicFoo
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a long-running `next-version` branch with tons of deletions to files that had changed on `develop`, files that had been added in different places on both branches, etc.

I wanted to take the entire contents of the `next-version` branch into `develop`, all in one whopping merge commit.

The combination of the above commands that worked for me was:

```
git merge -X theirs next-version
# lots of files left that were modified on develop but deleted on next-version
git checkout next-version .
# files removed, now add the deletions to the commit
git add .
# still have files that were added on develop; in my case they are all in web/
git rm -r web
```

Not a new answer, just combining bits from many answers, partly to reassure that you might need *all* of these answers.

Answer (score 4):

Accept remote changes (`theirs`) and in case there are conflicts you get the following error:

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

so you may want to pull and accept their changes with fast-forward:

```
$ git pull -X theirs --ff
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with an example,
We have a `main` branch and a `dev` branch having some conflicts

Pull updates before checkout, so the main branch is up to date:

```
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout dev
```

Then merge:

- if you want to accept **incoming changes** from the main to be the source of truth:

```
git merge --strategy-option theirs main
```

- if you want to accept the current changes in dev as the source of truth:

```
git merge --strategy-option ours main
```

`ours` and `theirs` here are special words, they have meaning and are not custom, but `main` or `dev` could be any other two branches you want to merge together.

Comment: There will be merge commit right? But what if we don't want to merge the branches, but want to cherry-pick the conflicting commit instead?

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs using smerge-mode, to resolve all conflict markers using either mine or theirs, we can define:

```lisp
(defun aj/smerge-keep-mine-all ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (while (ignore-errors 'user-error (progn (smerge-next) t))
      (smerge-keep-mine))))

(defun aj/smerge-keep-other-all ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (while (ignore-errors 'user-error (progn (smerge-next) t))
      (smerge-keep-other))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed to specify origin main as the branch I was merging into.

```
git merge **origin main** --strategy-option theirs
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's Solved.**  To resolve all conflicts with below simple steps.

```
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master

git pull -X theirs

git pull origin master
```

Comment: `git reset --hard` will destroy every uncommitted change

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are already great answers here, I wanted to post this answer to document how to resolve all merge conflicts in **Visual Studio 2022** (in favor of **our** changes as an example).

If instead, you want to accept incoming changes (**their** changes) as asked in this question, just replace `ours` in **Step 6** below with `theirs`. It's as simple as that.

---

**Summary of what I'm doing here:**

Merge *dev* into *my branch* and while doing that if there are any merge conflicts, take changes from my branch.

(After this is done, I'll create a PR to finally push the changes from *my branch* to *dev*).

---

### Step 1

Checkout the branch where you want to merge `dev` into by going to '*Manage Branches*' and double clicking your branch name. In my case, it's `feature\InterimBranchToDev2-AshK`.

[image]

### Step 2:

Right click `dev` and click `Merge 'dev' into 'feature/InterimBranchToDev2-AshK'`

[image]

### Step 3:

You'll see a ton of merge conflicts! 
[image]

Now it's very tedious to right click each of those files and click `Keep Current (feature/InterimBranchToDev2-AshK)`, so let's `Abort` this and take care of this using command line.

[image]

### Step 4:

Hit `Abort`

### Step 5:

Open `cmd`

[image]

### Step 6:

Type `git merge --strategy-option ours --no-commit dev` and hit enter

What this basically means: *"Merge dev into current branch and if there are any merge conflicts, take version from current branch, and also don't commit the merge yet".*

This will be the output:
`Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested`

### Step 7:

Now go to Visual Studio, conflicts are nicely taken care of and you can enter your message and commit:

[image]

Comment: Great answer, specially step 6. Thank u.