# Git merge error "commit is not possible because you have unmerged files"

Tags: git, git-merge

I forgot to `git pull` my code before editing it; when I committed the new code and tried to push, I got the error "push is not possible".

At that point I did a `git pull` which made some files with conflict highlighted. I removed the conflicts but I don't know what to do from here.

I tried to `git commit` again but it says the "commit is not possible because you have unmerged files":

> ```
> error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
> ```

Comment: You might want to change your git workflow so that you never arrive in this situation in the first place. I don't have time to elaborate on it right now, but what I have in mind includes either [git merge -X theirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364506) or [git pull -X theirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777677). - Probably not both, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

If you have fixed the conflicts you need to add the files to the stage with `git add [filename]`, then commit as normal.

Comment: What if those are the files I have not been working on?
Should I then still add them? What is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: I had to do this for a file that was deleted in a branch that I was merging into the current branch. Git flagged it as a conflict, so I had to delete the file locally then `git add the_file` in order to commit the merge.

Comment: how to find list of conflicts?

Comment: `git status` will show you the files that have conflicts

Comment: @jonnystoten thanks for your comment! I used `git status` and found a file that said `both deleted`. WebStorm UI didn't show the problem, just said it couldn't commit a merge. Resolved!

Comment: I think the answer "git add" is correct, but not complete. If I have a merge conflicts during cherry-pick and do "git add" + "git commit" as suggested I get the error: "fatal: cannot do a partial commit during a cherry-pick.". In this case I have to do this: "git add" + "git cherry-pick --continue" + "git push".

Comment: If you do not want to add that file in your commit and you are getting the error even after resolving the commit, simply stage and un-stage that file fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 69):

You need to do two things.
First add the changes with

```
git add .
git stash  

git checkout <some branch>
```

It should solve your issue as it solved to me.

Comment: It is not required only git add . would suffice

Comment: Also this is a heavy hitter if you're not wanting to `git add` all your working files

Comment: Do not run "git add ." unless you are ready to add all local files to your GitHub repo.

Comment: please don't use stash .. it we remove all u changed

Comment: This way you will get rid of the blocking message, but resolved conflict changes will also be rolled back. If you want to keep them - copy `src` folder, do what's in this answer, and paste `src` back.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `git stash` to save the current repository before doing the commit you want to make (after merging the changes from the upstream repo with `git stash pop`). I had to do this yesterday when I had the same problem.

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs when you resolve the conflicts but the file still needs to be added in the stage area. git add . would solve it. Then, try to commit and merge.

Answer (score 6):

Since git 2.23 (August 2019) you now have a shortcut to do that: `git restore --staged [filepath]`.
With this command, you could ignore a conflicted file without needing to add and remove that.

Example:

```
> git status

  ...
  Unmerged paths:
    (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
      both modified:   file.ex

> git restore --staged file.ex

> git status

  ...
  Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
      modified:   file.ex
```

Comment: is there anyway to apply this command to all files, since I've quite a lot of files needing merge, and applying this command to each file by name will be quite hectic task

Comment: @Lint You can apply for all files within a path. For example: `git restore --staged .` or `git restore --staged folder/`

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue which boiled down to removing files under "unmerged paths"

Those files had to be removed using `git rm`

Answer (score 0):

So from the error above. All you have to do to fix this issue is to revert your code. (`git revert HEAD`) then `git pull` and then redo your changes, then `git pull` again and was able to commit or merge with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the option "reset HEAD" under Git in Android Studio.