# git merge not possible because of deleted files

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I had a pretty big merge conflict which I solved. I cannot commit to resolve the confict, though.

When I want to commit with `git commit - m "Resolved conflicts"` I get an error like this

> error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.

When I look at `git status`, I can see that in my branch and the merged branch, a file is deleted - which is recognised by git:

[image]

You can see that in the `both deleted` notation.

I cannot - as suggested - add or remove the files. I get the error that the file is missing. This is correct because the file is deleted and therefore not on the file system.

Any ideas?

Comment: it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/12961752/9020340

Comment: @ArunPratap thx but i already solved it. look below :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, finally a solution!

You have to **add** every deleted file with the `-u` flag!

```
git add -u <file>
```

Quote from the docs about this flag:

> -u --update
>
> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching . This removes as well as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
> If no  is given when -u option is used, all tracked files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

Comment: `git add <path>` *without* `-u` will work too, even though the file does not exist. `git rm <path>` works even though it complains that the file is not there in the work-tree. In any case, if you want to use `-u` to finish everything at this point, you can use it *without* paths, as just `git add -u`, to update all the remaining removed files.

Comment: It took me ages to update all files. Great input that you can leave out the path!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while rebasing. For me I had to remove the file:
`git rm <file>`

before conintuing:
`git rebase --continue`