# Getting error while merging master branch into development branch using git

Tags: git, github, merge

I am getting the following error while merging the master branch into my development branch using git.

> Error:

```
error: Merging is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

I am explaining my process below.

1- I was working with my `dev` branch locally.

2- I checked out to `master` branch by using below below command.

```
  `git checkout master`
```

3- Then I pulled the latest code from `master` branch using the below command

```
`git pull`
```

4- Again I checkout to my branch using the following command

`git checkout dev (dev is my branch name which is cloned from master intially)`

5- Then I had to merge the `master` branch code to `dev` branch. so i performed the below command.

`git merge master`

6- Then only I am getting the above error.

Here I need to merge the latest code from `master` branch to `dev` branch and push into to remote `dev` branch. I need to resolve this error and merge the code.

Comment: git status should show you which files are to be fixed because they might have merge conflict makers in them, indicative of unresolved merge conflicts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT merge error "commit is not possible because you have unmerged files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961752/git-merge-error-commit-is-not-possible-because-you-have-unmerged-files)

Comment: How about doing `git rebase master` ? This will put your commits above the master's commits in the history tree

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what you need to do - you need to resolve conflicts in your files. Once they're resolved, you can do `git add -u`. After then, `git commit` and the merge will be complete.

Comment: I have resolved the conflict. In one file something was coming like `HEADER===` . I removed those but after that when I am trying to do the git merge again these errors are cming.

Comment: First I did `git merge master`  I got `CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in `mean-stack/node-js/app.js, Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`. After that I cleared those lines from app.js.

Comment: Again I did same `git merge master` after removing the lines like `HEADER===` but getting the error which I have posted.

Comment: after you clear the lines you need to do `git add -u` and `git commit`

Comment: I will do but the new codes from app.js master branch is not merged into my local branch app.js.

Comment: Now when I am checking git status. Its giving me `You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)`.

Comment: After you clear the lines, the first thing to do is `git add -u` and then `git commit`. That's how you fix conflicts, can you try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223093/discussion-between-subhra-edqart-and-ignoring-gravity).