# Resolve merge conflicts using the "theirs" option (In favor of the merged branch)

Tags: git, git-merge

So I have two branches, lets say Branch A and Branch B I have merged branch A into branch B.

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

Now I want to resolve differences in favor of branch A in command line. How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull)

Comment: You **have** merged (meaning you're done merging) or are you in the middle of that merge with conflicts?

Comment: I mean I have already merged it, and am in the conflicted state.

Comment: Those are contradictory claims: if you are in conflicted state, you are still in the act of merging. (In fact, you're still merging up until you run `git commit` to conclude the merge, even once you `git add` the resolved files.)

Comment: Alright. What I mean is perhaps then I have run the git merge command, have conflicts, have not yet committed anything, and have to resolve conflicts (usually by hand) and commit. However now I just want to use the branch that has been merged and commit, I am at the state of resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the the `-s recursive -Xtheirs` option for `git merge`.

This option does the **opposite** of the following:

> ...This option forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring 'our' version. Changes from the other tree that do
>   not conflict with our side are reflected to the merge result. For a
>   binary file, the entire contents are taken from our side...

Since you've already started the merge, you're going to want abort it since you cannot apply this merge strategy during a current merge.

`git merge --abort`

then re-do the merge as follows

`git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs`

That will do the merge so that all of the 'conflicts' are auto-picked to be from branch `A`

Comment: While you cannot change the *strategy* (it's too late, the strategy has already run its course), you *can* actually merge each individual file with the equivalent of `-X theirs`. But if you have not done any work you want to save, your method (`git merge --abort` and restart with `-X theirs`) is the way to go since that automates what you would otherwise have to do quite tediously, one file at a time.

Comment: And how to merge individual files in `-X theirs` style? I did some work on resolving manually and now want to resolve leftovers as theirs.