# How can I accept all current changes in VSCode at once?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I tried to merge one file with another file, but there are many HEADs with Accept Current Change | Accept Incoming Change | ...

Is there a way to accept all current changes at once?

Comment: If someone is looking for an answer to do this in Visual Studio (instead of VSCode), take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605102/8644294

Answer (score 386):

It's very easy just go to vs code and press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (command palette) or go to view and open command palette manually and type "merge" in your command palette, now you can see the Accept all current changes.

[image: you can see image here]

Comment: what about all the files!

Comment: do we have to select conflicted files first on the left panel? Since for my case it seems we do

Comment: This only accepts conflicts for the current file

Comment: for me even if I select all the conflicting files and use this method, later I need to click on them one by one and click Accept Merge button.

Answer (score 142):

select the list of files to resolve from the **MERGE-CHANGES** section, then right-click your mouse and select **Accept all incoming**.  That should do the trick for all files.

You will need to save the updated files once the conflicts are resolved. Click **File** and then **Save All**

[image: Select list of files]

[image: Right click and choose Accept all incoming]

[image: Click File and then Save All]

Comment: Did not work for me. The conflicts persist even after following the exact same steps.

Comment: Turns out this only works when only files are selected and their parent directories are excluded. You can select each file holding `Ctrl` key and then choose the option *Select All Changes* from the cascade menu. All the files will open with unsaved changes. To save all the unsaved files at once, do *File > Save All*.

Comment: If you still see conflicts - `Save all Files`

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I have 1000+ files in various directories having conflicts. Clicking the _Accept all current_ option doesn't do anything (_Accept all incoming_ works though). I had to select files in groups of about 30 files and select the option, followed by _Save all_ and _Close all_

Comment: I have one conflicting file.  It's binary (don't judge) so I can't preview changes.  Right click / select that one file, "Accept all Incoming" does nothing.  Same with command palette action.

Comment: Be careful, don't select the "Deleted" files. If the files you selected contains "deleted" files, it will make "Accept all incoming" do nothing.

Answer (score 41):

Select target file, right click and choose 'Accept All Incoming'.

[image: Screenshot of described step.]

Comment: Hi komoLei, can you please give a better explanation to your problem?

Answer (score 31):

As For **VSCode MacOS**, I've done `Accept All Incoming` from `Merge Changes` section, but it didn't affect all (that may be a bug, or I don't know why).
So, I used the conventional way with command line, and it worked.
**For accepting all incoming changes,**

```
git checkout --theirs .
```

or 
**For accepting all current changes,**

```
git checkout --ours .
```

P.S. Hope it helps for those who need to solve merging conflict first **in any case**.

Comment: After running this command, "Unmerged paths" remain until running `git add --all` which is very confusing... because they are... merged.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select all files in `Merge Changes` section.
2. Choose `Open File` from right click menu. It opens all files.
3. Select all files again.
4. Choose appropriate menu from right click. eg. `Accept All Current`.
5. Choose `Save All` from `File` menu.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the answers here worked for me. However, I was able to accept all incoming changes by running these commands manually.

I was in the conflict state at this point so I had to abort the merge and then pull all  "their" (incoming) changes.

```
git merge --abort
git pull -X theirs
```

Answer (score 0):

After accepting all upcoming changes, I have to unstage all changes and stage the changes again to make it work
[image]