# Avoid the merging of files that have changes on both branches

Tags: git

*Context: I am trying to get git behave like some other source code management tool while trying to convince them to only use git. In the meantime I need to run git as a slave, doing all the same things as the scm in action.*

How can I force git to use the strategy [`-X theirs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#merge-strategies-theirs) on file level instead of hunk level?

Basically if I have two hunks from two branches in the same file, git is capable to merge those to include both. But instead of that I want to overwrite the whole file of `mybranch` with the file of `theirbranch`.

EDIT:

Same can be done the other way round, to merge with strategy `-X ours` on file level and overwrite changes on `theirbranch` if there are changes on the same file on `mybranch`.

Comment: manually `git checkout <rev> -- <file>`?

Comment: Looks like you can even force the --theirs strategy at merge level : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull

Comment: Sure. Wait a few minutes for me to compose the answer.

Comment: @Matt recursive merge with strategy theirs will only take theirs when a conflict occurs. If I change the 1st line of a file in one branch and the 20th in the other branch git will merge that without errors and not applying `theirs` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697551/5958455), if you want to perform a merge with their changes, you can use `git merge -X theirs`. This, however, cannot be applied on a file basis.

If you want to discard "our" changes and use "their" version of the file, you can just perform a checkout:

```
git checkout <their revision or branch> -- <path to file>
```

Or, as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21777677/5958455), there's also a `--theirs` option when in the conflict state:

```
git checkout --theirs <path>
```

Just don't forget to `git add` and `git commit` after resolving conflicts.

---

If you want a list of files with differences in two branches (two arbitrary commits):

```
git diff <branch 1> <branch 2> --name-only
```

Comment: This is how I will do it. Just instead of doing a `git checkout` I will be overwriting the files from the other scm.