# Automatic merge conflict resolution

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I get a merge conflict in `index.js` when running this:

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git merge master
```

The `feature` branch `index.js`

```
const a = 1;
const b = 1;
```

The `master` branch `index.js` (This is where `feature` branch was born)

```
 const a = 1;
```

The `master` branch `index.js` (Current state)

```
 const a = 2;
```

I want automatically resolve the conflict in such a way so that `index.js` on `feature` branch was updated to this:

```
const a = 2;
const b = 1;
```

Comment: Right! We would all like to have that..... but git can't do it.... nor any other decent VCS. Merging engines can't just guess how to put code together... they try their best and, given your two tips of the branches (can't see the common ancestor, right?) you will get a conflict.

Comment: perhaps `git rerere`can give you a little hand? I have never used it myself so can't really tell how to use it. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Comment: When you've done more merges you'll have seen many textually-indistinguishable cases where the correct merge resolution isn't the one you want here, and you'll also have more skill using the merge resolution tools so doing the right thing, once you're sure what that is, will take about a second.

Answer (score 3):

Like the comments mentioned, Git is only so good at deciding how to put code together. You might be interested in merge strategy options though. You can run

`git merge --strategy-option theirs` or `git merge --strategy-option ours`

To favor either the source or the destination when it comes to conflicts. Read more about it here:

[Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull)

https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using `-X ours` or `-X theirs` (or their longer spelling equivalents, `--strategy-option ours` and the like) here.

The conflict that Git sees—remember, Git works line-by-line—is that in the *merge base* commit Git sees:

```
const a = 1;
```

In one of the two branch tip commits (let's call this the left hand side or `ours` one) Git sees:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 1;
```

This, to Git, looks like:

- *at the a=1 line* (which matches) *add* `const b = 1;`

Meanwhile, in the other branch tip commit, `theirs` or the right hand side, Git sees:

```
const a = 2;
```

To Git, this looks like:

- *at the a=1 line* delete a line, and insert `const a = 2;` instead

Both instructions "touch" the `a=1` line, so Git declares a conflict.

If you tell Git to favor "ours" / the left hand side, Git will keep the *add `b = 1` line* instruction, and *throw away* the *delete `a = 1` and insert replacement line* instruction.  If you tell Git to favor "theirs" / the right hand side, Git will keep the instruction that replaces `a=1` with `a=2`, but will *throw away* the other instruction.

Either way, you'll end up with the *wrong* resolution.  The right resolution is actually to accept both changes *even though they appear to conflict*.  Git has no way to do that automatically.

What I like to do for this case is to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.  That way, when Git leaves the messy merge conflict result in my work-tree, the file reads:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
const int a = 1;
const int b = 1;
||||||| merged common ancestor
const int a = 1;
=======
const int a = 2;
>>>>>>> master
```

With the default, the seven vertical bars and `const int a = 1;` base lines are *missing* (and sometimes the remaining lines are squished together even more).  It's very hard to read.  With the `diff3` style, the base lines are *there:* you can see what everyone started with, and make your own decision whether to take both changes, just one change, or some third alternative that's better than either.

(See also http://psung.blogspot.com/2011/02/reducing-merge-headaches-git-meets.html)

Comment: I wonder how to make git generate such ==== things like in your example when I do `git pull`. I already have `[pull]  rebase = true [merge]  conflictstyle = diff3` but it says it won't pull until I stash my changes. Then I stash and work on resolving if needed, but why can't it put things together for resolving when I do `git pull`? I want to start the process in 1 command, not 2.

Comment: @Nakilon: with `rebase = true`, `git pull` doesn't run `git merge` at all. Instead, it runs `git rebase` as its second command. (Remember that `pull` is just a convenience shortcut meaning *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to do something with what I just fetched*. The point of this is that `git fetch` just *gets* commits, but doesn't *do anything with them*, and after you get them, you eventually need to do something *with* them. Personally, I like the option of *looking at them* between the fetch step and the action, and `pull` prohibits this, so I avoid `pull`.)

Comment: In any case, it's `git rebase` that requires the stash-or-otherwise-clean-up step. Rebasing itself consists of repeated cherry-picking, and *each* cherry-pick is a form of merge, but an unusual one. There is a way to make `git rebase` automatically run `git stash` for you, but I recommend *not* doing this. As I just noted, I also recommend avoiding `git pull` itself: use the individual commands yourself, so that you can see what you are doing (and can stop in between commands if and when that's useful to you).