# Resolve git merge conflict without human input

Tags: git, git-merge

Would it be possible to execute a git merge of 2 files with conflicts on only certain lines without having to resort to human input?

See below for example, is there some option flag for git merge that can complete this without having to require additional input from the user?

test1

```
line1
```

test2

```
line2
line3
```

test2 after merge

```
line1
line3
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Git cannot know what your intent is there, or why keeping `line1` and `line3` is the right way to resolve that conflict.

Comment: `git rerere` _might_ help you.

Comment: “Would it be possible to execute a git merge of 2 files with conflicts on only certain lines without having to resort to human input?” if there were, it wouldn’t be a conflict. After all, there are built in strategies already. If none of those suits, that’s that.

Comment: As @matt said, any possible resolution would have been done. In Git, a conflict does not mean a problem, it means that Git is telling the user: "Hey, I did what I could to merge these changes, but there are some I am not sure about, and I need your help with it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a language with known structure, you could try to decompose it to smaller items than lines and get rid of some conflicts. There are some proprietary [solutions](https://www.semanticmerge.com/) which are advertised to do it (I have not tried them).

But for many conflicts it is not possilbe to solve them even with that approach. For example, user1 adds a like, and user2 adds another line to same place. Which one should go first? It is something only human can decide.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Automatic merge conflict resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518742/automatic-merge-conflict-resolution/55519346#55519346)

---

Like the comments mentioned, Git is only so good at deciding how to put code together. You might be interested in merge strategy options though. You can run

`git merge --strategy-option theirs` or `git merge --strategy-option ours`

To favor either the source or the destination when it comes to conflicts. Read more about it here:

[Resolve Git merge conflicts in favor of their changes during a pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull)

https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

Comment: Note that using this may cause unexpected disappearance of changes. I suspect many [complains](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+discards+changes) about merges discarding changes can be attributed to the options. The safest option would be the [union driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-union) which would most probably break any code but should be ok for human-readable text