# Git merge develop into master ignore conflicts

Tags: git

I have two branches: develop and master. I want to merge develop into master. When I follow

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push origin master
```

Git spits error messages like

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in CHANGELOG.TXT
```

How to tell git to just put all the stuff from develop to master ignoring all conflicts?

Comment: You generally can't avoid merge conflicts, but you can tell Git whose version you want to use, q.v. the duplicate link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull) might also be an appropriate duplicate, with more votes and answers on it.