# Ignore conflicts in file for git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I am doing a very large git rebase where the only expected conflicts are changes to a version number in a txt file. Is there a way to either ignore this file during rebasing, or always use the local or remote version for this file?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull) should answer your question, I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be :

1. first rewrite the history of your branch to remove all modifications on version.txt
2. then rebase

You can achieve 1 using `git filter-branch`

Say you want to rebase branch `my/branch` over `master`:

a. Find the merge-base between `my/branch` and `master` (you will use this commit to describe the range of commits you need to rewrite with `git filter-branch`) :

```
# get the hash of :
git merge-base my/branch master
```

b. Discard the modifications on version.txt : one way is to always use the version which is currently on master

```
# in the commit range, use the 'merge-base' hash instead of eacf32 :
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git checkout master version.txt`  eacf32..my/branch
```

c. Rebase :

```
# from branch my/branch :
git rebase master
```